# Name of this selectable scroll in unity editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]
As you can see in the picture, "Layout0" is selected with dark blue color.

I want to make this box too in my custom editor, but what I actually found is that this is not *EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView* and other whatever stuffs.

could someone please tell me the keyword of this selectable box?

Comment: Its highly likely that it is built with, or using, one or more private gui methods that would be difficult (if not impossible) to replicate.

Comment: Of the question is only about the coloring you can do `var oldColor = GUI.color; GUI.color = Color.blue; /*your stuff here*/; GUI.color = oldColor;`

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure how the highlighting works but here's how I think it's implemented.

1. Make a scrollable view using `GUILayout.BeginScrollView`
2. Make a vertical view, but with help box style `GUILayout.BeginVertical(EditorStyles.helpBox)`
3. For the highlighting, create a blue texture and assign it to a GUIStyle, which you then use for the button. Do this on Awake so you only do this once.

   ```
   Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
   for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
   {
       for(int y = 0; y < 1; y++)
       {
           texture.SetPixel(x, y, Color.blue);
       }
   }

   texture.Apply();

   this.selectedStyle = new GUIStyle();
   this.selectedStyle.normal.textColor  = Color.white;
   this.selectedStyle.normal.background = texture;
   ```
4. Change the buttons to label buttons `GUILayout.Button("name", currentSelected ? this.selectedStyle : GUIStyle.label)`